# Python file reading after file is all read

Tags: python, python-2.7, input

Using python 2-7:

```
msg = self.infile.read(1500)
```

I am reading pieces of 1500Bytes from a file **inside a possibly infinite while loop**,
when the file is all done and I have read it all what happens? Would I be reading again from the start? (I don't want that)

Is there a simple way to count how many chuncks of 1500B strings (or less for the last one) I have read in total without saving them?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are grabbing 1500 Byte chunks and not just processing per line?

Comment: Why not just try it on a small file and see what you get when you hit the end? Would have been quicker then typing up the question.

Comment: drahkar yes i am sending frames over a network and this is my allocated payload size, cmd i tought other newbies to python like me could benefit from the questions as well

Comment: You need to use @Drahkar (with the "@") in order to notify the person you are replying to.

Comment: @TomFenech the comment was not posted when I tried...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hold a counter:

```
ct = 0
while 1:
    msg = self.infile.read(1500)
    if len(msg) == 0:
        break
    else:
        ct += 1
```

After the loop ends the `ct` variable will hold your number of chunks.

Comment: The `else` is redundant

Comment: I just realized that you are actually answering part of his question that most everyone else had been looking over.

Comment: @Drahkar I didn't mean that the `ct += 1` was redundant as well, I just meant that there's no need for an `else` branch. I think that using `not msg` rather than `len(msg) == 0` is better (and so does the [style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/))

Comment: `if len(msg) == 1500: ct += 1; else: break;` is better when last chunk is not `0`

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

While I'll leave the below notes I added here, other answers in here are better meeting your requirements.

Specifically adding a

```
if not msg:
  break
```

Into the loop will take care of stopping the infinite loop when you reach the EOF.

---

As you haven't detailed why you are grabbing 1500 Byte chunks, I'm going to suggest an alternative per line solution. Assuming that self.infile is a file descriptor.

```
msg = [ line for line in self.infile ]
```

This will give you a list with each line from the file in a separate element with index '0' being the first and index 'n' (ie the last element in the list) being the last.

Answer (score 0):

You can read `chunk` using `iter` like this

```
>>> with open('infile') as infile:
...     for chunk in iter(lambda:infile.read(1500), ''):
...         if len(chunk) == 1500: # skip if size of chunk is less than 1500
...             print chunk # you can deal with `chunk` and count it here
```

Or you just want know **count**

```
>>> os.stat('infile').st_size/1500
```